# selector name with symbol

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

for some reasons i have html code wihh div code
`<div style="display:none" id="module:1">`
i dont want to remove ':' from div id and it makes problem when use the full name inside css  selector

````
#module:1 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10000;
}```


 how can keep this name inside css
````

Comment: Please consider editing your post and making such that it's not in all caps.